# Evernote dev: How can I see a list of apps/tokens and get my consumer key(s)?

Tags: api, evernote

I can't see anywhere on https://dev.evernote.com/ where I can find:

- a list of apps on this developer account
- a list of the developer tokens and secret keys

Also, different parts of the docs refer to "consumerKey" and "API key", is this the same thing?

Comment: It appears that https://www.evernote.com/api/DeveloperToken.action could be the location for this info, but that pages says "You do not currently have a developer token." - even though I received an email from Evernote dev saying my key has been activated.

Comment: That page also says "Update: the creation of developer tokens is temporarily disabled."

Answer (score 0):

As for the developer token, you can request enabling it for your production account by [submitting a support ticket](https://www.evernote.com/SupportLogin.action). I believe API key usually means consumer key and secret, and I don't think Evernote has a page to list consumer keys you've created.

Comment: I have already done this. I have the API key, but not the secret.

Comment: If you are referring to a text that can be obtained on evernote.com/api/DeveloperToken.action, that is a dev token (http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/dev_tokens.php), not an API key (http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php).